# how to select all in another program?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I want to Select all a text in another program, by using " SendKeys".
I did it for a Notepad file:

```
IntPtr appHandle = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
        if (appHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Specified app is not running.");
            return;
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(appHandle);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

        SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
```

but in the program that I want to select all its text, ctrl+a is considered for other command.

What should I do?

Comment: is it a notepad file or not , because if it is in notepad `ctrl+a` is the select all command

Comment: so what application is it

Comment: to see what is the select all command in the app that you use

Comment: if you don't know the select all key , so you cant use send key , you should read all text from it using stream readers but you say it isn't a text file, so unless it doesn't have any API`s to communicate with it , you cant do anything

Comment: is it a .txt file , yes or no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all you should use Ctrl+A
get handle of the application and send Ctrl+A

```
SendKeyDown(KeyCode.CONTROL);
SendKeyPress(KeyCode.KEY_A);
```